# Is it possible for input to be always focused like in Telegram desktop app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, focus

I have a question.
Is it possible for input to be always focused like in Telegram desktop app?

[image]

Comment: Use the [`autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If they did it for Telegram desktop then it must be possible, right? Just a matter of how.

There's a few ways to do this.

You can use the autofocus attribute as Ram mentioned in the comment. Simple, but I like to avoid HTML attributes for this kind of DOM manipulation because you're at the mercy of the browser understanding and implementing the attributes.

You can also give it a tabindex 1, but that means you'll have to keep track of your tabindexes for all focusable elements.

You can also write up a quick function under document ready like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#InputFieldID').focus();
});
```

These are only a few solutions I could think of off the top of my head.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need input need to be always focused not autofocus, the focus should not be off even when pressed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is this:

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
    document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("blur", (e) => {document.getElementById("myInput").focus()})
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
```

I hope I helped you